# Did Frodo meet any of Valar or Maiar when he sailed to Valinor?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

It's possible he could have. It's the home of the Valar and Maiar. Since the elves could not fully cure Frodo's wounds we might assume that someone of their power would do it.   Aside from Gandalf, I don't remember any canon source of Frodo meeting any other Valar or Maiar. I don't know of any source that says what happened after Frodo set sail for Valinor.

Is there anything canon, interviews, or anything by Tolkien addressing this?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The question title asks if it was possible, but your question body immediately admits that, yes, of *course* it's possible, and then you seem to be asking about if they met *specific* Valar. What is your actual question?

Comment: Also, though I sometimes dislike being nitpicky, please try and watch your spelling.

Comment: @JasonBaker you are right Jason

Comment: @JasonBaker I've edited it back to my original statement before the add-on

Comment: Gandalf is a Maia, so yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, of course he *could* have.

However, there is no indication of whether or not he did or, if he did, *who* he would have met. Tolkien never wrote about the details of Frodo's (and Bilbo's) time in the Undying Lands, except to say that they eventually died there.

From his letters, Tolkien seemed to regard merely *being* in the Undying Lands as being a form of healing; from Letter 154, for example:

> [I]n this story it is supposed that there may be certain rare exceptions or accommodations (legitimately supposed? there always seem to be exceptions); and so certain 'mortals', who have played some great part in Elvish affairs, may pass with the Elves to Elvenhome. Thus Frodo (by the express gift of Arwen) and Bilbo, and eventually Sam (as adumbrated by Frodo); and as a unique exception Gimli the Dwarf, as friend of Legolas and 'servant' of Galadriel.
>
> I have said nothing about it in this book, but the mythical idea underlying is that for mortals, since their 'kind' cannot be changed for ever, this is strictly only a temporary reward: a healing and redress of suffering.
>
> <sup>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 154: To Naomi Mitchison. September 1954</sup>

There may be some theology behind this that's beyond my knowledge, but there doesn't appear to be any specific expectation that Frodo would need "tending to."

Comment: You have such a way with words my lad! Have you ever considered being a Teacher?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to strengthen the already excellent answer supplied by saying that it's *almost a certainty*.

1. Frodo went to Valinor ([*Home of the Valar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_(Middle-earth)))

   > In Tolkien's works Valinor is the home of the Valar (singular Vala), spirits that often take humanoid form, sometimes called "gods" by the Men of Middle-earth. Other residents of Valinor include the related but less powerful spirits, the Maiar, and most of the Eldar. Valinor lies in Aman, a continent west of Middle-earth.
2. It was a *exception* allotted to Frodo

   > However, only immortal beings were generally allowed to reside there; exceptionally the surviving bearers of the One Ring were allowed to dwell there for a time — Bilbo and Frodo Baggins and also Samwise Gamgee

Someone (or more) of the Vala must have made this decision, though not strictly necessary for the Valar to *meet* the ring-bearers, one can safely say of the Valar.

a. [Manwë](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_(Middle-earth)#Manw.C3.AB):

> He was the noblest and greatest in authority

b. [Lórien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_(Middle-earth)#L.C3.B3rien)

> His gardens in the land of the Valar, where he dwells with his spouse Estë, are the fairest place in the world and are filled with many spirits. All those who dwell in Valinor find rest and refreshment at the fountain of Irmo and Estë.

These give two examples of the nobility and generosity of the great Valar, coupled with the fact that they know of the crucial role played by Frodo in Saurons' defeat I'd say out of pure gratitude they would have come to see him. In addition, he is a *guest* in their land, it would be extremely rude of them to not grant him one audience for a meet and greet, at the very least.

Comment: I am pretty sure Tolkien said in one of the letters that they only got as far as Tol Eressëa.

Answer (score 1):

Frodo did come across the Balrog of Moria who is a Maia as well as Saruman in the Shire. The Maiar and Valar do incarnate and those who do I'm sure Frodo can see when he's at Aman. They tended to take on particular forms, but they did at times take others,

> the shapes wherein the Great Ones array themselves are **not at all times** like to the shapes of the kings and queens of the Children of Ilúvatar; for at times they may clothe themselves in their own thought, made visible in forms of majesty and dread.
>
> [*The Silmarillion*, emphasis added]